# How to use grepl to check if a string exists row-wise in R

Tags: r, string, dplyr

```
library(dplyr)
mydata <- data.frame(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                     fruit = c("orange", "jackfruit", "", "N/A", ""),
                     fruit2 = c("orange", "guava", "", "", ""),
                     fruit3 = c("orange", "N/A", "orang", "", ""))

> mydata
  id     fruit    fruit2 fruit3
1  1    orange    orange orange
2  2 jackfruit     guava    N/A
3  3                     orange
4  4       N/A                 
5  5
```

I have a data set and I want to check if a string is present or not for each id. For example, the string "orange" is present for `ids = 1, 2`. The string "jackfruit" is present for `id=2`, etc.

Here's my attempt, but I got an error:

```
> mydata %>% group_by(id) %>% grepl("orange")
Warning message:
In grep(., "orange") :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Comment: What is the output you want?  A boolean column, or something else?

Comment: Boolean column would be great.

Comment: If you are trying for an exact match, you should be using `==` rather than `grepl()`.  `==` will be faster and has a method for data frames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how are you expecting as the output, but I thought of two ways to do it.

### Generic

#### Code

```
mydata %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -id,) %>% 
  filter(value != "", value != "N/A") %>%
  mutate(aux = TRUE) %>%
  select(-name) %>% 
  unique() %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = value,values_from = aux,values_fill = FALSE)
```

#### Output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 5
     id orange jackfruit guava banana
  <dbl> <lgl>  <lgl>     <lgl> <lgl> 
1     1 TRUE   FALSE     FALSE FALSE 
2     2 FALSE  TRUE      TRUE  FALSE 
3     3 FALSE  FALSE     FALSE TRUE  
4     5 FALSE  TRUE      FALSE TRUE
```

### Manual

#### Code

```
library(stringr)

mydata %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(
    orange = if_else(any(str_detect(c_across(cols = starts_with("fruit")),"orange")),TRUE,FALSE),
    guava = if_else(any(str_detect(c_across(cols = starts_with("fruit")),"guava")),TRUE,FALSE),
    banana = if_else(any(str_detect(c_across(cols = starts_with("fruit")),"banana")),TRUE,FALSE),
    jackfruit = if_else(any(str_detect(c_across(cols = starts_with("fruit")),"jackfruit")),TRUE,FALSE)
  )
```

#### Output

```
# A tibble: 5 x 8
# Rowwise: 
     id fruit       fruit2      fruit3   orange guava banana jackfruit
  <dbl> <chr>       <chr>       <chr>    <lgl>  <lgl> <lgl>  <lgl>    
1     1 "orange"    "orange"    "orange" TRUE   FALSE FALSE  FALSE    
2     2 "jackfruit" "guava"     "N/A"    FALSE  TRUE  FALSE  TRUE     
3     3 ""          ""          "banana" FALSE  FALSE TRUE   FALSE    
4     4 "N/A"       ""          ""       FALSE  FALSE FALSE  FALSE    
5     5 ""          "jackfruit" "banana" FALSE  FALSE TRUE   TRUE
```

Comment: What if a row is all ""? Your solution completely removes them from the output. I would like it to be FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE